# Move file at windows command line: exclude single file (substring of other files)

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Something that I thought would be trivial here, but I’m writing a batch file to move **web.config** files. In a number of folders I have the following files in them

```
web.config 
web.config.dev 
web.config.prod 
web.config.qa 
web.config.uat
web.config.preprod
```

and so on.
I want to leave the web.config file in place, as this is in source control, but the others aren’t and need to be moved. However, if I use:

```
move web.config.* <target>
```

all of the abovementioned files move, including web.config (which doesn’t have the trailing .!?). So I somehow need to exluce that from the file move.

I can't even do:

```
move web.config.?? <target>
move web.config.??? <target>
move web.config.???? <target>
```

As that still matches the web.config even with just web.config.??

Is there a way to do it with the wildcard (*) or some other command that I’m missing?

Comment: You could try to use `robocopy`. It allows you to exclude files and folders, supports regular expressions and is way more flexible than `copy`.

Comment: @MichaelS seems it can't be done with the basic DOS commands (e.g. move). Still not sure why web.config.* still matches web.config???
I've switched to robocopy and done it easily enough. Feel free to post this as the answer and I'll mark it as such

Comment: `for %%a in (web.config.*) do if "%%a" neq "web.config" move %%a <target>`

Comment: `*` matches zero or more abritrary characters, `?` matches zero or one arbitrary character; that's why `web.config.???` matches also `web.config`...

Comment: but web.config doesn't have the trailing space, so I see it would matched web.config. but why web.config?

Comment: @LDJ - You mean it doesn't have the trailing dot? File names are not allowed to end with dot or space, so trailing dots and spaces are stripped prior to comparing.

Comment: Sorry, trailing dot. Didn't realise trailing dots are stripped. Explains it - thanks :)